# Using shell script add a line to specific files

Tags: shell, search, addition, filenames

Can you please suggest me a shell script for doing the following:
I need to search for files with file names containing a specific string eg. search for all files with names containing substring "_ww.txt". Then to these files I need to add a comment "#found file" on the top.

Comment: Specify more: are all files in the same dir? What have you tried so far?

Comment: all files are not in same directory

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
  find . -name "*_ww.txt" -printf "#found\n%p\n"
```

Comment: Good one. Now I see I understood "_ww.txt" was to be in the file name, not inside it.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then simply replace "*_ww.txt" with "_ww.txt"